# Display custom fields in frontside user profile

Tags: plugin-development, users, profiles

I installed the [`CIMY User Extra Fields`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) plugin to add new custom fields in theuser profile.

I added 1 custom field for gender to the user profile but it displays only in the admin panel user profile. How to display on the front side registered user profile page?

Have any one idea.. Please send me step by step because new in WordPress.

Comment: yes it is plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Comment: When you say "front side registered user profile", are you talking about an ["author" page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)?

Comment: Yes, front side user profile page..

Answer (score 1):

According to the README_OFFICIAL.txt plugin file, you can use the `get_cimyFieldValue()` plugin function to retrieve user fields.

In your case, on the author page, assuming you have named the field `gender` the PHP needed to get the gender for the current author page is:

```
$gender = get_cimyFieldValue( get_query_var( 'author' ), 'gender' );
```

> Please send me step by step because new in WordPress.

`get_query_var( 'author' )` gets the author ID from the main query. `$gender` holds the value of the author gender. How exactly you would add this to your theme depends on how the theme displays the author page now.